# How to copy file owner mod number to file group through bash?

Tags: bash

I use `find . -type f -user apache ! -group apache` to find files as below:

```
[root@localhost www]# ls -all
-rw-r--r--  1   apache websites     191 Apr 23  2018 robots.txt
-rwx-rw-rx-  3   apache ftpuser      38 May 14  2018 functions
```

I want to revise the `group` mod of these files to the number same as `owner` mod.

For example as below:
In the file `robots.txt`, file owner `apache`'s mod is 6(from 644), then change group `websites`' mod to 6,then `robots.txt`'s mod changed to  664.
In the file `functions`,file owner  `apache`'s mod is 7(from 765),then change group `ftpuser`'s mod to 7,then `functions`'s mod changed to 775.

How to use `bash` script to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

`find . -type f -user apache ! -group apache -exec chmod g=u {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the stat command to retrieve the permissions by stat command:
[https://askubuntu.com/questions/152001/how-can-i-get-octal-file-permissions-from-command-line][1]:

```
perms=$(stat -c "%a" my_file.txt)
```

Then you can get the access rigths and split them:

```
user=${perms:0:1}
group=${perms:2:1}
other=${perms:2:1}
$myPerms=$user$user$other
```

Finally, just apply the new rights to the file:

```
chmod $myPerms my_file.txt
```

Some like this should work